# A RenderFlex overflowed by 1.9 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting a `A RenderFlex overflowed by 1.9 pixels on the bottom` error in my flutter app.

I wrapped all the ROW's in Expanded and I wrapped the main Column in a SingleChildScrollView but still have the issue. As you can see from the screenshots the view on the bottom scrolls up. The item on the top squishes down as it goes off screen. I am not even sure which Row is causing the issue?

UPDATE:

Seeing this now.

```
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 2) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Semantics widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  Column ← Expanded ← Semantics ← Align ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← LayoutBuilder ← DefaultTextStyle ← Align ← Transform ← ⋯
```

.enter image description here  [image]

[image]
CODE:

```
import 'package:animation_wrappers/animation_wrappers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qvid/BottomNavigation/Explore/explore_page.dart';
import 'package:qvid/Components/profile_page_button.dart';
import 'package:qvid/Components/row_item.dart';
import 'package:qvid/Components/sliver_app_delegate.dart';
import 'package:qvid/Components/tab_grid.dart';
import 'package:qvid/Locale/locale.dart';
import 'package:qvid/Routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:qvid/BottomNavigation/MyProfile/followers.dart';
import 'package:qvid/Theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:qvid/BottomNavigation/MyProfile/following.dart';

class UserProfilePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return UserProfileBody();
  }
}

class UserProfileBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserProfileBodyState createState() => _UserProfileBodyState();
}

class _UserProfileBodyState extends State<UserProfileBody> {
  bool isFollowed = false;

  var followText;
  final key = UniqueKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var locale = AppLocalizations.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: darkColor,
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  expandedHeight: 400.0,
                  floating: false,
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    PopupMenuButton(
                      color: backgroundColor,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.more_vert,
                        color: secondaryColor,
                      ),
                      shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return [
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            child: Text(locale!.report!),
                            value: locale.report,
                            textStyle: TextStyle(color: secondaryColor),
                          ),
                          PopupMenuItem(
                            child: Text(locale.block!),
                            value: locale.block,
                            textStyle: TextStyle(color: secondaryColor),
                          ),
                        ];
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    centerTitle: true,
                    title: SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Spacer(flex: 10),
                        FadedScaleAnimation(
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 28.0,
                            backgroundImage:
                                AssetImage('assets/user/user1.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Spacer(flex: 12),
                              Text(
                                'Emili Williamson',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/icons/ic_verified.png',
                                scale: 4,
                              ),
                              Spacer(flex: 8),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '@emilithedancer',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: disabledTextColor),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        FadedScaleAnimation(
                          child: Expanded(
                            flex: 2,
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                ImageIcon(
                                  AssetImage(
                                    "assets/icons/ic_fb.png",
                                  ),
                                  color: secondaryColor,
                                  size: 10,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 15,
                                ),
                                ImageIcon(
                                  AssetImage("assets/icons/ic_twt.png"),
                                  color: secondaryColor,
                                  size: 10,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 15,
                                ),
                                ImageIcon(
                                  AssetImage("assets/icons/ic_insta.png"),
                                  color: secondaryColor,
                                  size: 10,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Text(
                          locale!.comment7!,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              ProfilePageButton(
                                  locale.message,
                                  () => Navigator.pushNamed(
                                      context, PageRoutes.chatPage)),
                              SizedBox(width: 16),
                              isFollowed
                                  ? ProfilePageButton(locale.following, () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isFollowed = false;
                                      });
                                    })
                                  : ProfilePageButton(
                                      locale.follow,
                                      () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          isFollowed = true;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      color: mainColor,
                                      textColor: secondaryColor,
                                    ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 2,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              RowItem(
                                  '1.2m',
                                  locale.liked,
                                  Scaffold(
                                    appBar: AppBar(
                                      title: Text('Liked'),
                                    ),
                                    body: TabGrid(
                                      food + lol,
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              RowItem('12.8k', locale.followers, FollowersPage()),
                              RowItem('1.9k', locale.following, FollowingPage()),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  delegate: SliverAppBarDelegate(
                    TabBar(
                      labelColor: mainColor,
                      unselectedLabelColor: lightTextColor,
                      indicatorColor: transparentColor,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard)),
                        Tab(
                          icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage(
                            'assets/icons/ic_like.png',
                          )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  pinned: true,
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: TabBarView(
              children: <Widget>[
                FadedSlideAnimation(
                  child: TabGrid(dance),
                  beginOffset: Offset(0, 0.3),
                  endOffset: Offset(0, 0),
                  slideCurve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
                ),
                FadedSlideAnimation(
                  child: TabGrid(food + lol),
                  beginOffset: Offset(0, 0.3),
                  endOffset: Offset(0, 0),
                  slideCurve: Curves.linearToEaseOut,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ```scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,``` inside your ```SingleChildScrollView``` ? is it a typo ?

Comment: Yes, but when I change it to Axis.vertical the app keeps pausing with "Main isolate is paused in the debugger."

Comment: Once i had this problem, i wrapped with `fittedBox`

Comment: @jdog It would be quicker to restart than fix this. Nearly the only thing right with this code is that the `body:` of a `NestedScrollView` is a `TabBarView`. My suggestion is to remake this widget after reading the docs and learning how Slivers/ScrollViews are meant to be used. Trust me, it'll be easier. So that you know I'm not just trying to be mean, here are a few issues to consider:

Comment: @jdog why is your `TabBar` in a `SliverPersistentHeader` inside `headerSliverBuilder:`, rather than in the `bottom:` field of your `SliverAppBar`? Why do you have `Expanded` widgets directly inside a `SingleChildScrollView`? How are they meant to know when to stop expanding? Why do you have a `SingleChildScrollView` inside your `FlexibleSpaceBar`? If you just want to drag up the bottom widget, why aren't you using `DraggableScrollableSheet` instead of `NestedScrollView`?

Comment: Thanks for the info. All of the SingleChildScrollIViews and Expanded was because both are suggestions on how to fix this issue all over the internet. Just keep adding them until the issue goes away so I can see which one if any solves the issue. Whoever developed flutter and put a yellow/black thing didn't think this through. You can't tell which component(s) are actually the problem.

Comment: This isn't my code. Its downloaded from a learn Flutter project. I am trying to go through the code to learn and figure out how things works. I am trying to fix this guys issues. It looks like his code is like this. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlexibleSpaceBar-class.html

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused in this row. Remove this row and see if you still see the same problem in the Row above it. If you do then i guess it has something to do with the code below it. Is the code below this one also in singlechildscrollview or expanded? if its not then add it. i'm on phone so it's hard for me to clearly see the syntax.

```
                Spacer(),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          RowItem(
                              '1.2m',
                              locale.liked,
                              Scaffold(
                                appBar: AppBar(
                                  title: Text('Liked'),
                                ),
                                body: TabGrid(
                                  food + lol,
                                ),
                              )),
                          RowItem('12.8k', locale.followers, FollowersPage()),
                          RowItem('1.9k', locale.following, FollowingPage()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: I removed it and it has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As document says, You cannot use the `Expanded` widget inside the child of `FadedScaleAnimation`
You should only use the `Expanded` Widget as the direct child of `Row/Column/Flex` because these are flex widgets

Try putting `FadedScaleAnimation` inside `Expanded` Widget in your `Column` widget, the `Expanded` widget should be the direct child of your `Column`